# Lambda Expression to remove row with a condition from DataView

Tags: c#, lambda, dataview

I have the following:

```
 DataView studentInfo=ds.Tales[0].DefaultView;//Assuming I have a DataTabe ds with data
 studentInfo.RowFilter=myRowfilter
```

I want to do something like:

```
studentInfo(x=>x.remove(all students where some function returns true)
```

I don't want to use the rowfilter. I know I can add a clause there to filter the row.

Answer (score 0):

Use OfType<>

```
view.Table.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
               .Where (row => row["Name"] == "Candy")
```